# In Capistrano recipe, detect if Apache is installed, then stop it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, capistrano

Using Rails 3.2, Capistrano 2, I have the following nginx recipe:

```
namespace :nginx do
  desc "Install latest stable release of nginx"
  task :install, roles: :web do
    run "#{sudo} add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable"
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y update"
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y install nginx"
    run "#{sudo} /etc/init.d/apache2 stop" # Stop Apache because we are using nginx, only for production
    start
  end
  after "deploy:install", "nginx:install"
end
```

This is part of setting my VPS from scratch, you notice that I stop Apache before nginx is started, so that there will not be port conflict. But this works only when Apache is installed, if there is other OS which doesn't have Apache preinstalled, then this deployment recipe would throw error, trying to stop Apache which does not exist.

How can I improve this script? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to ignore the error if apache weren't found, you can try to replace the command with

```
run "#{sudo} /etc/init.d/apache2 stop || true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the command to

```
run "#{sudo} pkill -9 apache"
```

In case you are using any monitoring tool such as `monit` or `god`, then they may try to start apache again. In that case, use

```
run "#{sudo} netstat -tulpn | grep ':80 ' && /etc/init.d/apache2 stop"
```

to check if any process (not just apache) is listening on port 80 and then issue stop apache if it is